# I need to authenticate against one db with python and openfire. How do I do this?

Tags: python, database, openfire

How would one go about authenticating against a single db using Python and openfire?  Is there a simple module that will do this?

Answer (score 0):

Openfire uses a SQL database. So talking to the database from python is probably the easiest way.

You could also try to connect/authenticate via XMPP - there's probably an xmpp library for python somewhere.